# Meteor returning $ undefined

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am migrating my website into meteor so that everything loads at once.

I thought I could migrate the following code without changing anything:

```
$('#precommit').hide();
$('#arrowca').hide();
$('#arrowcb').show();

$('#clickc').toggle(function() {
  $('#clickc').html('Collapse');
  $('#precommit').show();
  $('#arrowcb').hide();
  $('#arrowca').show();
    height();
}, function() {
  $('#clickc').html('Expand');
  $('#precommit').hide();
  $('#arrowca').hide();
  $('#arrowcb').show();
    height(); 
});
```

However, what seems to be happening is that it is returning an error saying '$' is not defined.  However, I searched around and this should be analogous to meteor.startup.  Can anyone explain why this isn't working here, and how I best solve it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You placed that server-side didn't you?

Comment: woops... thanks a lot

Comment: functions dont seem to work now... but I guess that is a different issue I will look into now

Answer (score 0):

Many of what you have here seem like Jquery events. To use Jquery events, Meteor has a built in events function that acts very similarly to plain Jquery events and also uses Jquery in the background. `Template.myTemplate.events({ '#jquery-id-selector click': function() { $('.jquery-class-selector').hide();} });` You can also access the Jquery object within any template function such as created, rendered, helper functions, etc using `Template.$`.